# Why can’t you use a generic Self reference in a Swift 3.2/4 KeyPath typealias?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift4, swift3.2

Why can’t you use a generic Self reference in a Swift 3.2/4 KeyPath typealias?

Example: the below code compiles unless you uncomment the line marked `// B`. Why? From what I can reason, the line marked `// B` should mean exactly the same thing as the line marked `// A`, due to the statement `typealias Path<T> = KeyPath<Self,T>`.

Am I missing something here, or is this a Swift compiler bug?

```
protocol Fooer {
    associatedtype T
    typealias Path<T> = KeyPath<Self, T>
    var baz: T { get }
}

protocol FooPathContainable {
    associatedtype F: Fooer
    associatedtype T where F.T == T
    var fooerPathA: KeyPath<F,T> { get set } // A  
    var fooerPathB: F.Path<T> { get set } // B  <— causes compiler crash with Segmentation Fault 11
}
```

Answer (score 0):

root, value of keypath, inside angular brackets, is required to declare a keypath. It is like declaring Array with type in Swift.
This should work:

```
 var fooerPathB: F.Path<F, T> { get set }
```

Comment: See the updated code sample above. Somehow the first time I pasted it in, the <T>’s got deleted by the StackOverflow iOS app. But yeah, I do use F.Path<T> which is a typealias for KeyPath<F,T>, so it should totally work...

Comment: It is compiling for me in XCode9/Swift4

Comment: You are saying that the updated code sample that I provided is compiling on your XCode?

Comment: @CommaToast Yup compiling for me; on a playground and also inside a project. Try clean->quit xcode->deleting derived data.

Comment: Sorry, please check the updated code sample. There was yet another thing that the StackOverflow app had deleted when I posted it. Evidently it thinks generic arguments inside <> are HTML tags to be stripped, LOL.

Comment: But I wonder if we may have accidentally stumbled upon the answer this way. Hmmm...